# A pip module is available to python3.4 but getting an error when importing to python3.5

Tags: python, pip

Ok, the general problem is that I can install a module say:

```
pip3 install xlsxwriter
```

and I can call it using python3.4

```
python3.4 >>> import xlsxwriter
python3.4 >>> success!
```

however when I run it in python3.5 I get an error

```
python3.5 >>> import xlsxwriter
python3.5 >>> ImportError: no module named 'xlsxwriter'
```

I'm using Ubuntu Server 15.10 as my test box.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Install it with `pip3.5` instead of just `pip3`. `pip` installations are specific to a Python version.

Comment: Does `pip3` point to python 3.4 or 3.5? Run `pip3 --version`; it should tell you what version of Python it's running on. Please edit that into your question.

Comment: I was unaware that pip worked like that. That makes a tremendous amount of sense though. So best solution would be to just create an alias that points to 3.5?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that you have two python different python versions (3.4 and 3.5) that look for modules in two separate places.  What this means is that python 3.4 will look for modules in a folder in the python 3.5 directory while python 3.5 will look for modules in a folder in the python 3.4 directory. To fix the issue that you are having, you must install the module in the python 3.5 directory.  To do this go your command prompt and type:

```
cd C:\Python35\Scripts  # this is where I have my python 3.5 folder change the destination to where you have python 3.5 installed
pip install xlsxwriter
```

This should fix the issue. Hope it works!